# Removing controlling field values (picklist dependencies) during deployment

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, ant, continuous-integration

We have multiple orgs on which we are running deployments using jenkins and ant deployment tool.

We have problem when removing dependencies during deployment. 
So basically I'm able to remove dependencies in my org, retrieve the changes and later commit them to repository.
But unfortunately after successful deployment to another org those changes are not taken into account at all. 
Dependant values are still controlled by old ones.
How to overcome this issue? Besides of course manually change those dependencies in the target org

Comment: [this should help](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_field_types.htm?search_text=controlling%20field)

Comment: What exactly do you mean? We are removing controllingFieldValue from value settings but it still persist after deployment (or whole valuesettings if there is such need)

Comment: are you deploying both the CustomField for the picklist as well as the Custom Field for the controlling field?

Comment: Im deploying whole project which includes object with both picklists (and standard value sets)